# Exclude specific files from being processed by a specific PostCSS plugin in vite.config.js file

Tags: vite, postcss

I'm trying to migrate my project from Webpack to Vite. Webpack has ability `test` files in this way

```
test: /\.scss$/, <-- TEST
use: [
  {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      postcssOptions: {
        plugins: [
          [
            // List of Postcss plugins....
          ],
        ],
      },
    },
  },
]
```

In Vite, any PostCSS plugins applied to all CSS files (include files from `node_modules` ) and SCSS files by default.